# array map() receives [object Object] instead of item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My purpose is to render 5 stars in a line:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedStar: '',
        ...
    };

    this.starsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // is used like indexes
}

onStarPress = (index) => {
    console.warn('index = ' + index); // index here is [object Object] instead of 1, 2, 3 ...
    this.setState({
        selectedStar: index
    });
}

renderStars = () => (
    this.starsArray.map((starIndex, i) => (
        <Star
            key = {i}
            color = {this.defineStarColor(starIndex)}
            onStarPress = {(starIndex) => {this.onStarPress(starIndex)}}
        />
    ))
)
```

When I do `map()` to the array of indexes `starIndex` is equal to `[object Object]` instead of 1, 2, 3 ...

`i` here does equal to 1, 2 ... as the `key`. But when I pass it to the functions below it also becomes `[object Object]`

What I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: `(starIndex) => {this.onStarPress(starIndex)}` -> `() => {this.onStarPress(starIndex)}`

Comment: It's my real code. This is a snippet that is related to a problem part (rendering stars). I believe that you don't need snippets with rendering other elements since they don't influence on this.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick Roberts! The issue was really because of `starIndex` in the first brackets.

Comment: No problem. If you set up JSLint, it would catch problems like that since you're shadowing the reference

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `Star` invokes your function, but if it's just using the given function as an event handler, then you are receiving the event object as your first argument. Hence, it's an object.

If you want it to pass on the index, have the `Star` component handle the DOM event, and call your supplied function with the expected arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `onStarPress = {(starIndex) => {this.onStarPress(starIndex)}}`, the first `starIndex` is event handling object. So `onStarPress` is receiving an object.

There are two ways to solve this:

```
onStarPress = (e,index) => {
    console.warn('e = ' + e); 
    console.warn('index = ' + index); 
    this.setState({
        selectedStar: index
    });
}

renderStars = () => (
    this.starsArray.map((starIndex, i) => (
        <Star
            key={i}
            color={this.defineStarColor(starIndex)}
            onStarPress={(e) => { this.onStarPress(e,starIndex) }}
        />
    ))
)
```

Other way is:

```
onStarPress = (index) => (e) => {
    console.warn('e = ' + e); 
    console.warn('index = ' + index); 
    this.setState({
        selectedStar: index
    });
}

renderStars = () => (
    this.starsArray.map((starIndex, i) => (
        <Star
            key={i}
            color={this.defineStarColor(starIndex)}
            onStarPress={this.onStarPress(starIndex)}
        />
    ))
)
```